# "Melted" vs "molten"

Tags: word-usage, differences, adjectives, past-participles

Is there any difference (e.g. regionality) between the two forms of the past participle of *melt* (*melted* and *molten*)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're not really alternatives. Molten specifically refers to liquids which are extremely hot, and whose usual form is as a solid. It is used as an adjective.

By contrast, something may be melted (whether used as a transitive verb, or an adjective), but need not be hot, and it need not be liquid (something that has begun to lose solidity can be considered melted), nor does it even need to still be subject to the melting process (i.e. it may have fully resolidified).

Comment: Unlike "molten", "melted" is used in a looser sense too which also covers "dissolved".

Comment: This answer is good from linguistic perspective that explains the use; however in more strict, technical meaning I like the following definition: "An object that has melted completely is *molten*."

Comment: @Unreason: To be honest, I think molten has lost its meaning as a participle.

Comment: @Marcin, see use in books in 21st century - http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&tbo=1&q=molten&btnG=Search+Books#q=molten&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099&sa=X&ei=aKQRTsGOBYir8AP9-I3VDg&ved=0CBUQpwUoAQ&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=7caa2b99db8bf4b5&biw=963&bih=789

Comment: also visible from http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=molten%2C+melted&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3, after '40s the frequencies closely correlate

Comment: @Unreason: All those books titles appear to be using "molten" as an adjective.

Comment: @Marcin, yup sorry, mind went off

Comment: So its proper usage isn't based on logic, but on the whims of the elite. Despite English being an international language, only a few cultures set the standards for everyone else.

Answer (score 2):

Marcin's answer is, I believe, very good, from the perspective of every day usage. However both terms relate to concepts in physics, so let me give some more perspective.

If you look in wikipedia entry for [molten/melting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melting) you'll find this distincion:

> An object that has *melted completely* is *molten*.

This is further enforced by dictionary definitions, but also expanded with what used to be colloquial use,

> **[mol·ten](http://www.yourdictionary.com/molten)** (mōlt′'n)
>
> *transitive verb, intransitive verb*
>
> - (Archaic) melt
>
> *adjective*
>
> - melted or liquefied by heat
> - (Now Rare) made by being melted and cast in a mold

and for melt

> [melt](http://www.yourdictionary.com/melt) (melt)
>
> *transitive verb, intransitive verb*
>
> - to change from a solid to a liquid state, generally by heat
> - to dissolve; disintegrate
> - to disappear or cause to disappear gradually: often with *away*
> - to merge gradually; blend: *the sea melting into the sky*
> - to soften; make or become gentle and tender: *a story to melt our hearts*
>
> *noun*
>
> - a melting or being melted
> - something melted
> - the quantity melted at one operation or during one period
> - a dish, esp. a grilled sandwich, containing or covered with a layer of melted cheese: *a tuna melt*

From these definition you can conclude that

- melting describes the process from the moment the object starts changing its shape (due to the fact that it is not solid anymore)
- melted is used for object that changed its shape due to melting, even though it might not be melted (in stricter sense) anymore and it completely re-solidified
- molten is typically used with *glass, lava, rock*, all of which all require to be very hot to be melted, so high temperature is usually implied (though strictly speaking it is not necessary)

So, you should make a distinction between a strict physical meaning and colloquial use. I believe that discrepancies due to loose vs strict meaning are much more pronounced than any distinction due to regional meanings.